# Solving a circular foreign key relationship with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, database-normalization

I have a database with the following data structure:

USER table:

```
Id  Name    
1   Alice
2   Bob
3   Charlie
```

FOLDER table:

```
Id  Name       User
1   Invoices   2
2   Contracts  3
3   Receipts   3
```

DOCUMENT table:

```
Id  Name                  User    Folder
1   Birth Certificate     1       null
2   Fax Machine Receipt   3       3
3   Work NDA              3       2
4   Laptop Invoice        2       1
5   Job Application       2       null
```

Here's the schema as I've conceptualized it:

[image]

The idea here is that a user has documents and folders, and those documents can *optionally* be sorted into folders. I need a constraint to ensure that a document is only sorted into a folder owned by the same user that owns the document (i.e. DOCUMENT(user) = FOLDER(user)), or a clever way to normalize the schema to prevent a scenario in which document's user doesn't match the folder's user.

Comment: What circularity? PS Why do you think this involved DB normalization? ("normalize" does't mean "rearrange" or "constrain" or "design well".) PS This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `("user", "folder")` a key in `"folder"` and reference that in `"document"`.

```
CREATE TABLE "user"
             ("id" serial,
              PRIMARY KEY ("id"));

CREATE TABLE "folder"
             ("id" serial,
              "user" integer
                     NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
              UNIQUE ("id",
                      "user"),
              FOREIGN KEY ("user")
                          REFERENCES "user"
                                     ("id"));

CREATE TABLE "document"
             ("id" serial,
              "user" integer
                     NOT NULL,
              "folder" integer,
              PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
              FOREIGN KEY ("user")
                          REFERENCES "user"
                                     ("id"),
              FOREIGN KEY ("folder",
                           "user")
                          REFERENCES "folder"
                                     ("id",
                                      "user"));
```

Another option would be to always have a default folder for every user and handle all by just a reference to `"folder"` then.

Comment: I didn't realize a foreign key could reference multiple columns like that. Thanks! I'll test this out in the AM

Comment: @Ataraxia: Formally a [(primary|foreign)] key is actually always a *tuple* of columns. But when it's a one-tuple and because humans tend to be lazy, that is simplified and we just say that the column (the one column in the one-tuple) is a [(primary|foreign)] key.

Comment: So, Postgres is telling me the "user" column on FOLDER has to be unique, which we don't want since I want a user to be able to have multiple Folders.

Comment: `a UNIQUE constraint does not exist on referenced columns: FOLDER in statement [ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.Document ADD CONSTRAINT fk_document_folder_user FOREIGN KEY (folder, "USER") REFERENCES PUBLIC.Folder (uuid, "USER")]`

Comment: @Ataraxia: You seem to haven't properly applied the unique constraint for `"folder"`. Make sure the tuple of both columns `("id", "user")` is declared unique not just a single column.